# How to pass environment variable to another job Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I have a repository in github and two jobs in jenkins: one is triggered by a webhook and thus launches the second one, where the backend is built and delivered. I need to pass the GIT_BRANCH variable from the first job to the second one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Job Parameter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) to the second Job. And then trigger the second Job like below from the first one.

```
build job: 'SecondJob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: "$GIT_BRANCH"]]
```

Comment: where do I need to add this? There are no scripts in the first job, except for the webhook

Comment: And first job is not a pipeline,I can't add parameters

Comment: @HavyZail If it's a freestyle JOb you can use https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/